# Jenkins - Publish TestNG Results in email

Tags: xml-parsing, jenkins-pipeline, xml-to-json

I’m running Automated test cases in Jenkins Core. I have an xml file with # of test cases passed, failed etc. I want to read the xml file() and publish the results in the body of the email. .Something like below . What other options do we have

TOTAL # of TESTS EXECUTED = 23

TOTAL # of TESTS PASSED = 20

TOTAL # of ESTS FAILED = 3

I do not have Publish TestNG Results even since we moved to Jenkins Core. xml parser is not an options in Jenkins core. I can use json parser. can i convert xml to json and then read?

Comment: Why not use XmlSlurper to parse the xml file?

Comment: can't use due to Org restrictions